# how do i change react mui mobilestpper dots color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

can't find how do i change the dots color
tried various changes in  makestyles including
dot: {
backgroundColor: "#008000 !important"
}
but nothing worked
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sslwl?file=/demo.js:423-480

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MobileStepper API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/mobile-stepper/#props), you need to supply your properties to the `classes` prop instead of `className`. An example for changing the color of the active dot:

```
classes={{
  dotActive: classes.dot
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixes are mentioned below.

- Define styles object correctly.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 400,
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  dot: {
    backgroundColor: "#008000"
  },
  dotActive: {
    backgroundColor: "#3f51b5"
  }
});
```

- Define classes prop in `MobileStepper` as per the [API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/mobile-stepper/#props).
- According to the API documentation, you can override the default style of the component in 3 ways. Here use 1st way & that is **using classes object prop**.

```js
<MobileStepper
  variant="dots"
  steps={6}
  position="static"
  activeStep={activeStep}
  classes={{
    root: classes.root, // this will overrides default styles related to MobileStepper root element
    dot: classes.dot, // this will overrides default styles related to dot elements
    dotActive: classes.dotActive,
  }}
  nextButton={
    <Button size="small" onClick={handleNext} disabled={activeStep === 5}>
      Next
      {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
        <KeyboardArrowLeft />
      ) : (
        <KeyboardArrowRight />
      )}
    </Button>
  }
  backButton={
    <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
      {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
        <KeyboardArrowRight />
      ) : (
        <KeyboardArrowLeft />
      )}
      Back
    </Button>
  }
/>;
```

Note - *If you override the default colour of dots, then you have to override the active dot colour also.*

https://codesandbox.io/s/mobilestepper-53cx2?file=/demo.js:343-522

Let me know if you need further support.